# Cursor to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, cursor

I'm getting cursor and converting it to JSONArray(don't know yet if i'm doing it right way) 
But im doing only for one table Tasks. I have 5 tables. Can i do one cursor for all 5 tables and pack them in one JSONOBject {{"tasks",JSONArray},{"projects",JSONArray}....} and so on.
what sql statement should i use to do that. I don't want to have a lot of similar code.

```
private JSONObject sendUserData(){
        // Building Parameters
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONArray jsonArrayTasks=null;
        Cursor cursorTasks=getAllTasks();
        int count=cursorTasks.getCount();
        if (count>0){
        jsonArrayTasks=getJSONFromCursor(cursorTasks);
        }
        cursorTasks.close();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", send_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tasks", jsonArrayTasks.toString()));
        JSONObject json = getJsonFromURL.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        Log.i("json", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    private JSONArray getJSONFromCursor(Cursor cursor){
        JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject returnObj    = new JSONObject();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

            for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
            {
                if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                        {
                            Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i) );
                            rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                        }
                    }
                    catch( Exception e )
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                    }
                }

            }

            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return resultSet;
    }

    private Cursor getAllTasks() {
        //     return database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_TASKS_NAME +" WHERE "+KEY_CATEGORY +" = " + categoryID,null);
        database=dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " +
                TABLE_TASKS_NAME +" A "
                + "," + TABLE_TAG_NAME +" B "
                + "," + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME+" C "
                + "," + TABLE_PROJECTS_NAME+" D "
                ;
        Log.d("Test query","Test query :"+query);
        Cursor test = database.rawQuery(query
                , null);
        return  test; //!!!!!!
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to convert the whole Cursor to json?

Comment: i want my code to look pretty

Comment: sorry,  i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Where you check cursor.getString(i) is null, consider first using cursor.getType() so you can handle all types.

Unless you have a need to join the tables (by using a JOIN expression in the SQL query) you should probably just make a separate call to database.rawQuery for each table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correct. You want to query 5 tables and want to put all of them in one JSONArray.
two things: -

1. If there is any relation between the tables then you can use join in your sql statement and it will fetch data from table. Now use the cursor to populate it in JSON format
2. If there is no relation then you have to query them separately. 5 cursors will be there to query 5 tables. Push each and every cursor one by one into JSONObject. Declare JSONObject as global to maintain the state. Or you can save it locally using Bundle or Sharedpref

Hope this will help you